# Swipe over an image with Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using j.query mobile.
I would like to get an alert when i swipe over an image with a class ".leaves".
Can i do it in the following way? it does not work.

```
function swipe(){
    $('.leaves').swipe(function(){
            alert('grrrr');
        });
}

swipe();
```

Comment: is the demo here: [Swipe to navigate](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/swipe-page/newyork.html) working for you?

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea about the structure but you can try this:

```
// to be sure that your page is created
    $(document).on("pagecreate", "#your_page_id", function () {
            $(document).on("swipeleft", ".leaves", function(){
                  console.log('swipeleft');
            });
            $(document).on("swiperight", ".leaves", function(){
                  console.log('swiperight');
            });
        });
```